# Retrieve multiple items in column filter and then delete the rows brought back

Tags: excel, vba

I used a macro to import a text file into Excel.  Now, I need to delete multiple items in each column.

In column A, I need to delete:2, --, St, T.  Those items are usually on the text file.  But sometimes, I get other numbers such as 13.

I want to filter Column A to select all of those items.  If possible, I also want to write a formula to select numbers less 24. This will help me in the long run. Then, delete the visible rows.

Second,  I need to filter column b, to select: From, and all blank rows. Then, delete the visible rows.  I know I can do this with a macro, but I am concerned that the macro will not work if the number of rows increase or a "new number" appears in Column A.

This is what I have so far:

```
Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("=St", "=T", "=2", "=--")
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Use the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to define the cells that your [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) will affect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to define the cells that your [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) will affect.

```
Sub filterIt()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

            'first array of criteia (St, T, 2, --)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                        Criteria1:=Array("St", "T", "2", "--")
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'determine if there are cells to delete
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'there are visible row - delete them!
                    Debug.Print .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(0, 0)
                    '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            'clear filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1

            'second numeric criteia
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<24"
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'determine if there are cells to delete
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'there are visible row - delete them!
                    Debug.Print .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(0, 0)
                    '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            'clear filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1

            'second numeric criteia
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                        Criteria1:=Array("from", "=")
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'determine if there are cells to delete
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'there are visible row - delete them!
                    Debug.Print .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(0, 0)
                    '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            'clear filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=2

        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Step through the code in the VBE by tapping [F8]. You can pause and observe what is going on with your worksheet. The range addresses of the visible rows are reported to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx). When you are satisfied with the procedure, remove the commented lines that actually delete the rows.

Comment: I gave a try to "..AutoFilter..Criteria1:=Array("St", "T", "2", "--")"  but didn't work for me. it only filtered on the last array item.  Do you actually get it work to have multiple filtering?

Comment: Yes, I did. Hang on a second and I'll post my sample workbook. Where you trying to wildcard the **St** and **T** or are those the entire cell value?

Comment: no wildcards try. I filled a range (from A1 to A30) with simple letters ("a", "b", "c"...) and then I randomly substituted some of those letters with "St", or "T", ... and the filter acted on the last array item only

Comment: See sample workbook [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/filterIt.xlsb).

Comment: I see. I omitted "Operator:=xlFilterValues" specification. it must have taken some default setting that didn't have autofilter operate with array as wanted. thank you Jeeped.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeletRowsByKeywords()

Dim dataDB As Range, headerRow As Range
Dim keywordsArray As Variant
Dim iKey As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    Set dataDB = .Range("A1:A100") '<== set it as per your needs and beware: it must include the first row as the header
    Set dataDB = dataDB.Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, dataDB.Columns(1).column).End(xlUp).Row) ' get only cells down to the last non empty one
End With
Set headerRow = dataDB.Rows(1).EntireRow '<== set the header row explicitly. it wil be hidden and shown multiple times

keywordsArray = Array("St", "2", "--", "T") '<== set your keywords for rows to be deleted

For iKey = LBound(keywordsArray) To UBound(keywordsArray)
    With dataDB
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=keywordsArray(iKey) ' filter data on current key
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            headerRow.Hidden = True
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' filter data again on Product Type
            headerRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
Next iKey

End Sub
```